Causal Inference: A Primer Study Question 1.2.3
I feel so stupid that I can't even answer the third question in the entire book, but I just cannot wrap my head around this. For reference, this question came right after an introduction to Simpson's paradox. Here is the two-part question:
Determine, for each of the following causal stories, whether you should use the aggregate or the segregated data to determine the true effect.
(a) There are two treatments used on kidney stones: Treatment A and Treatment B. Doctors are more likely to use Treatment A on large (and therefore, more severe) stones and more likely to use Treatment B on small stones. Should a patient who doesn’t know the size of his or her stone examine the general population data, or the stone size-specific data when determining which treatment will be more effective?
(b) There are two doctors in a small town. Each has performed 100 surgeries in his career, which are of two types: one very difficult surgery and one very easy surgery. The first doctor performs the easy surgery much more often than the difficult surgery and the second doctor performs the difficult surgery more often than the easy surgery. You need surgery, but you do not know whether your case is easy or difficult. Should you consult the success rate of each doctor over all cases, or should you consult their success rates for the easy and difficult cases separately, to maximize the chance of a successful surgery?
How would I even go about this? Intuitively, if we don't know whether the stone is large or small, we should just use the general population data. But then the same should be true of the second question, where we don't know what type of surgery we need. It feels clear that the textbook is trying to emphasize that there is a subtle difference between the questions, and I suspect it must have to do with the fact that we know each doctor has performed exactly 100 surgeries, but I just don't understand how that's relevant.
